# What standards exist within GNU as to where the help and version messages should be stored?

Tags: posix, standards, gnu

The [GNU Coding Standards](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/index.html) mentions that a compliant program must be able to process the `--help` and `--version` flags, printing the associated messages, then exiting the program, ([Section 4.8](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Command_002dLine-Interfaces.html#Command_002dLine-Interfaces)). They go further into how these messages should be formatted, but the language is rather vague as to *where* these messages should be stored. Further, it explains that the *program name* should be stored as a constant string and NOT computed based on `argv[0]`, ([Section 4.8.1](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/_002d_002dversion.html#g_t_002d_002dversion)). However, that seems to be as deep as they dive into the topic, as I couldn't find any references to whether the remainder of these messages are to be read from a file, hard coded into the program as a constant string, or any other way for this to be accomplished in a standardized way.

My question is, does GNU (or POSIX) provide any standardizations for this? Did I miss a paragraph in the book, or is it down to personal taste?

I've skimmed through the [GNU Coding Standards](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/index.html) book, and lightly touched parts of the [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html) standards, however, I was unable to find any further mentions on the topic.